# How do I customize a Pivot Table field calculation in Excel to use a specific formula?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-columns, powerpivot

My Pivot Table (PT) calculates a field (COGS) based on 2 other columns: 'Units sold' * 'Unit cost',
COGS Grand total should be its sum or a calculation Sum(Units sold) * AVG(Unit Cost)
Instead its Calculation is Sum(Units sold) * Sum(Unit Cost)
How/where do I override the PT's global calculation?

I reviewed the calculation setup but am unable to determine how to override the PT's global calculation to create a specific calculation?

Comment: To do this, you'll want to use Power Pivot. This will let you create custom DAX measures. Specifically for this, take a look at the `SUMX()` function.